# Display number with decimal places instead of whole number

Tags: c++

I have this

```
double a = 4.0;
double b = 2.0;
double g = a + b;

std::cout << g;
```

I am getting `6`, but I want to get `6.0`.

How can I do this

Comment: @PeteBecker got it, thanks. I've seen people conceptually think about that in the wrong manner, just wanted to make sure :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you always want one figure after the decimal point regardless of how many digits the answer is, use `std::fixed` along with `std::setprecision`

```
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << g;
```

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
#include <iomanip>
//...
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << g;
```

This sets the precision of the output to 2 significant figures.

Edit: as the other answer points out, prepend `std::setprecision` with `std::fixed`.

Comment: doesnt work for me. output is still 6. when I add 4.1 to 2.0 I get 6.1 but when it comes to "0" at the end of comma it doesnt show it.